# How can I call jQuery-UI components from a browser side XSL rendering of HTML using Saxon-JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, xslt, saxon

All mainstream browsers still support XSLT for rendering HTML from XML using XSLT, although most only support XSLT 1.0.  Version 2.0 and some 3.0 can be used via Saxon-JS.

The advent of popular Javascript libraries for rendering HTML (I happen to use jQuery-UI), not only produces the visual HTML, but connects the components to event listeners for behavior.

I would like the best of both worlds.  I would like to send XML to the browser to be rendered via XSL, but for interactive components, I would like to call the jQuery-UI renderer from my XSL.

Is this doable from an XSLT extension?  Will the Saxon-JS find the reference on the browser to the Javascript engine?

Comment: If you look at the Saxon-JS sample applications then you will see that they all have a HTML document calling Saxon-JS with Javascript as the starting point. The code then executes an XSLT 2.0/3.0 stylesheet populating some elements in the HTML document. I don't see any problems having some JQuery in there then calling e.g. a JQuery-UI dialog. I am not sure what you mean by "Will the Saxon-JS find the reference on the browser to the Javascript engine" exactly, whether it is Saxon-JS or JQuery or JQuery-UI, all three are Javascript libraries executed by the browser.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - I see what you mean.  Why not pre-process like the example for XSLT, then post-process to call the jQuery-UI.  I was stuck in the paradigm that I needed to do it all inline.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure it's something we have explicitly tested, but I *think* that you should be able to use Saxon-JS to do a conventional XML-to-HTML transformation, with no use of the capabilities to handle user interaction events, and instead handle the user interaction via some other framework invoked directly via Javascript. Saxon only registers event listeners for event types that appear as modes in the stylesheet, and even with those, if the event occurs on an element that is not matched by a template rule, the event will "bubble" up to other event handlers.

Comment: @MichaelKay I've made progress, but have [a more detailed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109940/calling-jquery-ui-components-in-xsl-using-saxon-js-and-its-global-javascript-fun).