# Calling jQuery-UI components in XSL using Saxon-JS and its global Javascript function namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, xslt, saxon, saxon-js

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44208134/how-can-i-call-jquery-ui-components-from-a-browser-side-xsl-rendering-of-html-us) question, you **can** call Javascript functions from XSL 2.0 transforms running in the browser using Saxon-JS.  But I can't seem to invoke the jQuery-UI calls.  My only thought is that it may be a timing issue where the jQuery selector can not find the target object's ID because Saxon-JS has yet to render it to the DOM.

My simple test follows...

The XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <date month="7" day="17" year="2017"/>
</data>
```

The XSL...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:js="http://saxonica.com/ns/globalJS"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:result-document href="#header">
            <hr/>
        </xsl:result-document>
        <xsl:result-document href="#editor">
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#999999">
                    <th colspan="2">Form</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="data/date"/>
            </table>
        </xsl:result-document>
        <xsl:result-document href="#footer">
            <hr/>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="date">
        <tr>
            <td>Date:</td>
            <td>
                <xsl:variable name="currentValue"><xsl:value-of select="@month"/><xsl:text>/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@day"/><xsl:text>/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@year"/></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="$currentValue"/>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>

                <xsl:value-of select="js:initDP('#datepicker','7/17/2017')"/>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>XSLT-JS-UI</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/SaxonJS.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="editor"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <input type="text" id="testDP"/>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="initDP('#testDP','7/17/1961')">picker</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Javascript...

```
//=====================================
function initDP(id,init)
    {
    $(id).datepicker();
    $(id).datepicker("setDate",init);
    } 
//=====================================
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    SaxonJS.transform({
        stylesheetLocation: "test.sef.xml",
        sourceLocation: "test.xml"
        });
    });
//=====================================
```

Included are both an HTML call to **initDP** (initialize jQuery date picker) and a XSL call to the same.  The HTML works, the XSL fails silently.

Comment: I'm hoping Michael Kay is out there somewhere and can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `xsl:value-of` Javascript call is evaluated before the result element is created or at least inserted in the document.

What has worked for me is to simply put a `script` result element after the `input`, creating the Javascript code on the fly:

```
<xsl:template match="date">
    <tr>
        <td>Date:</td>
        <td>
            <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="string-join((@month, @day, @year), '/')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$currentValue"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker{position()}"/>

            <script xsl:expand-text="yes">initDP('#datepicker{position()}', '{$currentValue}')</script>

        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Tested successfully with Firefox from the file system and over HTTP and with Chrome over HTTP (Chrome by default doesn't do XMLHttpRequest over the file system so Saxon-JS over the file system does not work). Edge does not seem to execute the XSLT and gives two "SCRIPT5022: XError: Misplaced or malformed XML" errors in SaxonJS.min.js (1,11772), IE seems to execute the stylesheet but the inline script does not seem to be executed. Online sample at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2017/ui-test1.html.

I have now also successfully test a different approach (https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2017/ui-test2.xsl) with Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer that instead of an inline `script` result element uses `ixsl:schedule-action` to call a template that then uses `js:initDP`:

```
<xsl:template match="date">
    <tr>
        <td>Date:</td>
        <td>
            <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="string-join((@month, @day, @year), '/')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$currentValue"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker{position()}"/>
            <ixsl:schedule-action wait="1">
                <xsl:call-template name="init-datepicker">
                    <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'#datepicker' || position()"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$currentValue"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </ixsl:schedule-action>                
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="init-datepicker">
    <xsl:param name="id" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:string"/>
    <!--<xsl:sequence select="trace(js:initDP($id, $value), 'init-datepicker called for ' || $id || ' at ' || current-dateTime())"/>-->
    <xsl:sequence select="js:initDP($id, $value)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The Edge problem seems to unrelated to the issue here to have Saxon-JS and JQuery UI interact, instead it is appears to be caused by a bug in the Javascript engine of the current Edge version, see https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/3366, which the Saxon-JS code runs into when checking for a misplaced XML declaration. If I remove the XML declarations in the XML input and Saxon's SEF package file then https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2017/ui-test4.html works fine in Edge as well as that way the Saxon-JS code does not run into the Edge Javascript bug.

Comment: I thought it was a timing issue, but it hadn't occurred to me to inline the script call.  Thanks.